# How can intelliJ run gradle task as test

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, gradle, integration-testing

I have a gradle project with "unit test" and "integration tests" tasks defined as follows:

```
test {
  include '**/*Test.class'
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  include '**/*IT.class'
}
```

I created a run configuration in IntelliJ to run all unit tests like image shows:

[image: Run configuration of gradle 'test' task in intelliJ]

And did the same with the task 'integrationTest':

[image: Run configuration of gradle 'test' task in intelliJ]

IntelliJ 'understands' the test task and run it showing graphical results, like in this image:

[image: IntelliJ showing the results of gradle test task]

The same doesn't happen when it runs the 'integrationTest' task. The results are shown in text, like when I run the task by command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question...
As far as I know you can't make IntelliJ to run tests of a specific task and the Pattern solution doesn't work so well.

So, the only way I found to effectively separate integration tests in IntelliJ was with the use of a JUnit Category.

1. Create an interface to represent integration tests.
   For example:

   ```
   public interface IntegrationTest {
   }
   ```
2. You have to annotate every integration test class with the category annotation and the created interface:

   ```
   import org.junit.experimental.categories.Category;
   import mycompany.mypackage.IntegrationTest;

   @Category(IntegrationTest.class)
   public class DbfFileProcessorIT {
       ...
   }
   ```
3. Create a build configuration filtering with Category:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add idea plugin to gradle works for me

```
plugins {
    idea
}
```